# Trying to figure out how to add a receptacle from the far 3 way switch

Tags: lighting, switch, multiway-switch

I've read answers to similar questions but I'm still confused. I'm trying to add an always on receptacle from the far switch of a 3 way switch circuit.

Right now the circuit is wired like this:
[image]

I don't have an always hot or neutral at the far switch.
Since I have access to the wiring at all switches and the light, I can easily completely splice the 2 cables at the light so they pass straight through to the second switch, that would give me this:

[image]

I'd have to run a second cable from the second switch back to the light in this case but that's not an issue.

I've heard that the answer to this is to get smart 3 way switches that only need one traveler between them, but I still don't see how that would solve the problem.

[image]

In this picture I'd still have to pass 3 wires out of the first switch box into the second, a black to the light, a red to the second switch and the white neutral.

This doesn't leave me any way to pass the red constant hot wire from the first switch to the second.

Am I missing something, or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: Is there a reason not to run a cable for the outlet from the first switch with the hot and neutral.  Outlets do not really care where the cable comes from, as long as it has hot and neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I have access to the wiring at all switches and the light, I can easily completely splice the 2 cables at the light so they pass straight through to the second switch, that would give me this:

That'll get neutral to the second switch, but it won't get always-hot there.

> I've heard that the answer to this is to get smart 3 way switches that only need one traveler between them, but I still don't see how that would solve the problem.

You didn't hear *from this forum* that the answer is to get smart 3-way switches **that need one traveler between them**.  We would never say that because it's wrong, as you correctly observe.

Let's use logic. For your plan to work, then in ALL your wiring:

- Black must be always-hot
- White must be neutral

Now we have 1 wire left, the red.  We need - mandatory - to carry **switched-hot**, from one smart-switch **or** the other... to the lamp.  So that crosses off the red wire.  How many wires do we have left for datacomm between the two smart switches? That's right. Zero.

**So you must use *particular* AC line-powered smart switches that use powerline-coded or wireless communication** to replace a 4th telecomm wire. Such as Insteon. That solves it.

Comment: It was in this thread that I first got the idea
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/161689/adding-an-outlet-to-a-3-way-switch-on-far-end#new-answer?newreg=00b3383a7707402e8b8a8f377b03e9d1

I didn't see any mention of wireless or powerline. That's disappointing. I was hoping it would be possible with the existing romex.

Comment: @vincatzero dude, I saw it mentioned.  Your reading comprehension is total cr*p.  I've already explained how to do it using the wiring in the walls, my last paragraph.  How come you missed that? Did you fail to read it or did I fail to state it clearly?

Comment: Well I guess I was looking for a better option then. 

I did some googling on the wireless options and they all seem to have connection problems or battery life problems so I didn't like that option.

I also looked at powerline stuff and read how it's not a great option either. 

So unless I'm missing something with one of those options, there's no way to hardwire the circuit the way I was hoping. 

I see it's possible to solve my problem given your answer, but none as well as I was hoping. 

Again, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @vincatzero By googling "wireless smart switches" you seem to have latched onto **battery remotes** which is the wrong thing here. You will have power at both switches, and they should be line-powered, so that they don't need batteries.   They are simply using wireless or powerline signaling to avoid needing a 4th wire.

Comment: I've looked and looked and I can't find any switches that match your description. Could you (or somebody else) link me to a pair of 3 way switches that can connect with 2 wires (black and neutral) and communicate wirelessly? Thank you

Comment: Are you still googling "wireless" and stuff like that, try "power line signaling 3-way".  Insteon as mentioned, or any of the X10 stuff. Just off the top of my head.

Comment: When I first googled Insteon switches all I kept seeing was articles about how they're out of business and their stuff wasn't working anymore. That was enough for me to write them off as an option. I went back and looked at the switches though since I obviously don't care if their servers were up, and they did look like exactly what I needed. So I bought 2 and am waiting for them to get here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was looking at the manual for the switches
http://cache.insteon.com/documentation/2477S-en.pdf

so I'm going to have a always-hot wire in both boxes using the black wire, correct? I'll have no use for the red wire at all anymore.

Comment: @vincatzero yes, that's the general idea.  Someone else must make what Insteon makes. It's too useful not to make.  Powerline and/or radio signaling is not that hard to implement. Heck, X10 makes it easy and X10 has been around since the 1980s.   You will probably need the red wire for part of the distance from the controlling switch to the light.

Comment: Got the switches in the mail and got them installed. They worked perfectly. Got a new GFCI outlet ran off the new always-hot wire in the switch box. Thank you. Really appreciate the help